# How to repeat div using jQuery or JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, jquery-mobile

I have an HTML page with the following div tags

```
<div data-role="page" id="pageHome" data-theme="a">
  <div data-role="content">
    <center>
      <h3><a href="#pageHome" data-role="none"><img src="images/logo.png" /></a></h3>
    </center>
    <div class="dydivarr0"> </div>
    <br />
    <div data-role="controlgroup" class="ui-btn-right"> <a href="#page1" data-role="button">Next</a> </div>
  </div>
</div>



<div data-role="page" id="page1" data-theme="a">
  <div data-role="content">
    <center>
      <h3><a href="#pageHome" data-role="none"><img src="images/logo.png" /></a></h3>
    </center>
    <div class="dydivarr1"> </div>
    <br />
    <div data-role="controlgroup" class="ui-btn-right"> <a href="#page2" data-role="button">Next</a> </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div data-role="page" id="page2" data-theme="a">
  <div data-role="content">
    <center>
      <h3><a href="#pageHome" data-role="none"><img src="images/logo.png" /></a></h3>
    </center>
    <div class="dydivarr2"> </div>
    <br />
    <div data-role="controlgroup" class="ui-btn-right"> <a href="#page3" data-role="button">Next</a> </div>
  </div>
```

dydivarr is generated dynamically from web a response using JSON. Using that response I create dynamic div content, next I want to repeat that div as shown above. Is there any better way than to repeat static html code? I guess there must be few jQuery or JavaScript tricks for that.

Any help would be appericiated.

Comment: Take a look at [`cloneNode`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Node.cloneNode)

Comment: Let me make sure I understand the problem correctly.  Youo make an AJAX request to populate data into the `mydivarr*` containers, but what you really want to do is to create the entire enclosing HTML structure (i.e. `data-role="page"` divs) dynamically as well based on the JSON result from the AJAX call?

Comment: why -2? atleast comment please

Comment: I did **NOT** downvote, but I can understand why somebody would. This question shows very little effort.  It's as if you said, "_here's what I want to do... I don't really feel like trying to learn the basics of JavaScript, so please give me some code to cut and paste._"  Again, I'm not the downvoter... But I don't see how you could be able to retrieve JSON from a post and **NOT** be able to answer your own question.

Comment: jahroy : may be you thinking I started this page before some hours and looking for some ready-made stuff may be others think too. but it's been 2 days I am behind this div and I don't know where I am doing wrong because I was thinking the best way to create this dynamic content at time of making my dydivarr only but it didn't work and even after lots of effort result didn't come I was thinking my approach may be wrong.

Comment: Like I said (twice)... I did not downvote.  I'm just explaining why it was downvoted (because it looks like no effort was made).  Yes, your approach is wrong.  You should create your divs dynamically with JavaScript.  If it's possible, you should consider using jQuery, which will make this much easier.  Unfortunately it appears that you lack the basic JavaScript skills to understand how to do this.

Comment: If you want better help, you should provide an example of what your JSON data will look like.  You should also start with something simple... Start with some JSON and try to dynamically create some **VERY BASIC** divs.  For example, I would start by trying to crate three simple divs that contain the words "_one, two, three_".

Comment: jQuery makes tasks like this very easy.  Check out [this link](http://api.jquery.com/append/).  It demonstrates how easy it is to add a div to the document's body... It would look something like this: `$('body').append('<div>Hello</div>');`

Comment: actually getting feed from wordpress blog using json plugin and then making every post as mobile page view so it's easy to navigate in small screen. that is why used json else I have read jquery is more useful to perform such task.

Answer (score 4):

So you want [cloneNode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Node.cloneNode) of your div, so try something like this

```
var div = document.getElementById('myDiv'),
clone = div.cloneNode(true);
clone.id = "some_id";
document.body.appendChild(clone);
```

Comment: Don't think that's what he needs. If you look at `id` and `href`, they aren't the same.

Comment: but contents of mydiv is not same. and if I am not wrong cloneNode() may lead to duplicate element IDs in a document I want diff id as I want to make it navigate next and previous

Comment: you can set the content ID as you want as well as other properties too.

Comment: but sachin it won't create a href="#page3" and inner div class dynamically then too viewing clone example but I think it may not solve the problem. though I never use it I can't conclude in 5 mins thanks for suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this? 
 [Sample Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/YmJ6F/)

```
var lastSection = $('[data-role="page"]:last'); //get the last page probably you can use this to increment the id based on last id
var newSection = lastSection.clone(false);//default is false anyways, if you want to carry over data and events you can use true.
newSection.attr('id','setthenewid');//set the new id
$('div[class^=dydivarr]',newSection).attr('class','newclass'); //set the new class for your divarr
$('.ui-btn-right a',newSection).attr('href','newurlmap');//set the new url map 
lastSection.after(newSection); //place the entire page section in the end
```

Answer (score 1):

Update :

Simple Code worked. It was just my wrong approach

```
<script type="text/javascript">

for(var lp=0; lp < 10; lp++)
{
document.write('<div data-role="page" id="page'+lp+'" data-theme="a">');
document.write('  <div data-role="content">');
document.write('    <center>');
document.write('      <h3><a href="#page0" data-role="none"><img src="images/logo.png" /></a></h3>');
document.write('     </center>');
document.write('     <div class="dydivarr+lp+'"> </div>');
document.write('     <br /> ');
document.write('     <div data-role="controlgroup" class="ui-btn-left"> <a href="#page'+(lp-1)+'"     data-role="button">Previous</a> </div>');
document.write('     <div data-role="controlgroup" class="ui-btn-right"> <a href="#page'+(lp+1)+'" data-role="button">Next</a> </div>');
document.write('   </div>');
document.write(' </div>');

}

</script>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

[How can I replicate a div a certain number of times based on a select-box value?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6309453/760661)

Roko C. Buljan

And

Vivin Paliath

's Answers