# How could I add the same string on different paragraph multiple time on the same HTML page?

Tags: javascript, html

I wish to know the best way to write only once the same thing and repeat inside the same page. For example:

```
<div>
    <p id="description1"></p>
</div>
<div>
    <p id="description1"></p>
</div>
--
```

I wish to write only one time the `description1` inside the `body`. I think this could be achieved using the DOM.

Comment: Give them the same class and different IDs. Then, as answered by neuhaus use getElementsByClassName to control it

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to repeat div using jQuery or JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16026425/how-to-repeat-div-using-jquery-or-javascript)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, the ID field should be unique per element.

If you give all the tags a class `<p class="description"></p>` then you can use jQuery to set them all by calling:

```
$('.description').text('This is the text')
```

In javascript:

```
var elements = document.getElementsByClassName("description");
for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
    elements[i].innerHTML = "This is the text.";
}
```

Comment: maybe he isn't using jquery... :-)

Comment: is it the same if I have 2 class?

Comment: Yes, it will update all elements that share the same class name. @neuhaus True, true...

Comment: since getElementsByClassName() returns a list, I don't think you can use innerHTML like that - have you tested it?

Comment: @neuhaus I didn't. Thanks for pointing it out, I've not used plain javascript much before. @Simone Yes, if you mean something like `<div class="my-red-box description">` then it will have the red box style and the text will also update.

Answer (score 4):

Put the elements in the same class using the `class` attribute, then get the list of all elements using the [getElementsByClassName()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_getelementsbyclassname.asp) DOM function. You can then go over the list using a [for loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9329446/for-each-over-an-array-in-javascript).

```
[].forEach.call(document.getElementsByClassName("description"), function(elem) {
        elem.innerHTML = "StackOverflow saved my day!";
});
```

You can even put the text in all elements of the same class using no JavaScript and only CSS by using the `content` attribute.

Comment: I don't think you can call `forEach` on a `NodeList` - easy way around this is using `[].forEach.call(document.getElementsByClassName("description"), function() { ... }`

Comment: I get this from console `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token` on  `function(elem) {`

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the solutions proposed here
[How to repeat div using jQuery or JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16026425/how-to-repeat-div-using-jquery-or-javascript)

this one seems to work pretty well:

html:

```
<div id="container">data</div>
```

js:

```
var container = document.getElementById('container');

function block(mClass, html) {
    //extra html you want to store.
    return '<div class="' + mClass + '">' + html + '</div>';
}

//    code that loops and makes the blocks.
//    first part: creates var i
//    second:     condition, if 'i' is still smaller than three, then loop.
//    third part: increment i by 1;
for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    // append the result of function 'block()' to the innerHTML
    // of the container.
    container.innerHTML += block('block', 'data');
}
```

[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/ag6patnj/)

Comment: grazie Simone, this is a very nice solution so basically I changed this `for (var i = 0; i < 0; i++) {`

Comment: @Simone seems typo err **for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++)**  ..not `i < 0`.:)

Comment: @theRoot I tried with JSFIDDLE i<0 ...in this way if you copy and paste the html code multiple time, you have the same description as reult. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

**two** elements **cannot** have **same id** but can have **same class**

```
 <head>
        <script>
            var x = document.getElementsByClassName("description");
            for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
                    x[i].innerHTML = "This is the text.";
            }
        </script>

        <style>
               .description1 {                    // this will apply the same style to all elements having class as description1
                  text-align: center;
                  color: red;
               }
        </style>
 </head>

    <body>
        <div>
            <p class="description1"></p>
        </div>
        <div>
            <p class="description1"></p>
        </div>
    </body>
```

**See the script tag. this solves your problem**

Comment: This is not an answer. Write these things into comments rather then answer.

Answer (score 0):

Just added with a code by using

> getElementsByClassName()

```
`<html>
<body>

<div class="example">First div element with class="example".</div>

<p class="example">Second paragraph element with class="example".</p>

<p>Click the button to change the text of the first div element with class="example" (index 0).</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<p><strong>Note:</strong> The getElementsByClassName() method is not supported in Internet Explorer 8 and earlier versions.</p>

<script>
function myFunction() {
    var x = document.getElementsByClassName("example");
    for(var i=0;i< x.length;i++)
    x[i].innerHTML = "Hello World!";
}
</script>

</body>
</html>`
```

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to keep id, change your code like this :

script :

```
var pcount = 2// # p
var desc = document.getElementById('description1');
for(i=0; i<pcount;i++){
   document.getElementById('description' + i).innerHTML = desc;
}
```

html

```
<div>
 <p id="description1"></p>
</div>
<div>
 <p id="description2"></p>
</div>
```